# Modify specific occurrences in a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a raw `HTML` `string` like below:

```
<p>ABC</p><p>- <em>Ví dụ</em>: CDF<a href="wwwabc">abc learning</a><code>Ctrl</code> <p><Img src="../../images/iconcss.png" alt="css" title="css"><div>hhhh</div><Img src="../../media/iconcss.png" alt="css" title="css"><span></span><Img src="../../images/flower.png" alt="css" title="css"></p>
```

I want to modify all the `<img>` tags and my expected string would be like this:

```
<p>ABC</p><p>- <em>Ví dụ</em>: CDF<a href="wwwabc>abc learning</a><code>Ctrl</code>
<p><Img src="/static/images/iconcss_1.png" alt="css" title="css"><div>hhhh</div><Img src="/static/media/iconcss_2.png" alt="css" title="css"><span></span><Img src="/static/images/flower_3.png" alt="css" title="css"></p>
```

My ideas are to extract all the `<img>` tags from the `string` and push them into an array A:

> var A_array = ["<img....>", "<img....>", "<img....>", "<img....>"}]

and also split the string by the `<img>` tags and make an array B. Then I can be able to modify each and every `<img>` tags from array A.
Then of course I can create my expected output by joining A and B.

But I am really struggling how to realize it as `<img>` tags's src are inconsistant. Please help me on this!

Comment: In what way are the src strings inconsistent?

Comment: I mean the src content is different from others!

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve but can you not simply make use of the DOM selectors like `document.getElementsByTagName('img')`?

Comment: So is there a reason you can’t just replace each occurrence of ../.. with /static in your string?

Comment: This is in ReactJs, these imgs are stored on client side and I have to use "require" in order to make the image display. I just want to get the proper img path by using "require" and replace them into the string above

Comment: @AHaworth: Technically, I just don't know how to replace each of them with my own content!

Answer (score 0):

I eventually ended up with this solution:

```
function correctImageSrc(htmlData){
    const imgTagOccurence = `<img src="`;
    if(!htmlData || htmlData.indexOf(imgTagOccurence) === -1){
        return;
    }

    const noneImgArr = htmlData.split(imgTagOccurence);

    const output= noneImgArr.map(item=>{
        if(htmlData.indexOf(imgTagOccurence + item) === -1){
            return item;
        }
 
        // Extract img src between the double quote
        const imgSrc = item.split(`"`)[0];
        const remaining = item.replace(imgSrc, "");

        return [imgTagOccurence, addMyOwnContent(imgSrc), remaining].join("");
    });

    return output.join("");
}
```

I still hope that there would be better approaches!